# Wildfly 9 console - changed its look and feel

Tags: wildfly

Something happened and WF console changed to this look and feel, can you please advise?

[image: All of a sudden the console changed]

Previously:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/images/stories/wildfly9/ds-templates1.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Need to read release notes:**

http://wildfly.org/news/2015/06/10/WildFly9-CR2-Released/

> WildFly 9 CR2 is released!
>
> I’m happy to announce the WildFly 9.0.0.CR2 release! This release
>   addresses a number issues discovered during the CR1 cycle, and also
>   includes **a major UX update to the console**.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to have the old console switch back to cr1.