# Adding a datasource to wildfly via web console

Tags: java, mysql, jndi, wildfly

I have searched for days now and cant get any further.
I am trying to assign a MySQL datasource to my Wildfly 9 server via web console.
If I add the resource I'll get an error in testing the resource due a bug in wildfly 9 which creates the resource with a max-pool-size of 0.
So i edited it by myself and everything seems fine.
Now when i try to lookup that resource in my webapp, Its just a classic servlet application which produces some json data, i get an error.
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException.
The jndi-name of the resource is : java:/MySQLDS

This is the XML generated via web console:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/MySQLDS" pool-name="MySQLDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/test</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <driver>mysql</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
        <initial-pool-size>0</initial-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
        <allow-multiple-users>false</allow-multiple-users>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>user</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        <use-fast-fail>false</use-fast-fail>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
        <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>
        <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
        <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
        <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
    </timeout>
    <statement>
        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

In my app I have a class which manages my connections in a hashmap for various reasons.

```
public class DBConnection {

    static {
        try {
            context = new InitialContext();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static InitialContext                       context;

    /**
     * JNDI Lookup cache
     */
    private static final HashMap<String, DataSource>    connectionCache = new HashMap<String, DataSource>();

    private DBConnection() {
    }

    public static Connection getConnection(String shema) {
        DataSource ds = connectionCache.get(shema);
        if (ds == null) {
            try {
                ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:/" + shema);
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connectionCache.put(shema, ds);
        }
        try {
            return ds.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This produces the error above.

Now the strange part:
I removed the resource from web console and added exactly the same resource via a *-ds.xml file in my WEB-INF folder and it works!

```
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema">
    <datasource jndi-name="java:/MySQLDS" pool-name="MySQLPOOL">
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/test</connection-url>
        <driver>mysql</driver>
        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
        <security>
            <user-name>user</user-name>
            <password>password</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

The question is how can I add resources via web console and find in my app?
And why i am able to find the resource if i add the resource via xml but not via web console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now I feel retarded..

I simply had to reload the server configuration.
I though it would be enough to just add the resource and you are ready to go!

On a single page deep inside Wildfly it said it has to reload the configuration. So I did and now everything works.

Sorry for being that dump.

Comment: This is not dumb, it is a bit confusing, I was also getting "cannot create jdbc connection - reload required" - but took me a while to find this "reload" button.

Comment: i just updatet to cr2 and now the web console is all messed up :D
Now it looks like a mobile view. And a lot of labels are overlapping -.-
And the reload button is all gone, which doesn't mean you have to reload the server. Now its all about you to restart the whole service .. God damn it. Does anybody have the same problems?

Comment: Welcome to the club: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803655/wildfly-9-console-changed-its-look-and-feel/30846127#30846127

Answer (score 1):

This is my datasource, it works fine (created via web console).

```
           <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/NotesUsersDS" pool-name="NotesUsersDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users?autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;amp;characterSetResults=utf8&amp;amp;connectionCollation=utf8_unicode_ci;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1</driver>
                <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                    <initial-pool-size>0</initial-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>256</max-pool-size>
                    <allow-multiple-users>false</allow-multiple-users>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>users_user</user-name>
                    <password>my_password</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <use-fast-fail>false</use-fast-fail>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
                <timeout>
                    <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
                    <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
                    <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>
                    <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
                    <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
                    <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
                </timeout>
                <statement>
                    <track-statements>true</track-statements>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>128</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
```